# how did they get this answer for the words that don't have bba and abb?

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions and I am looking at the answer in solution manual which asked ,

> Regular expressions -- Let the alphabet = {a,b}.

Write regular expressions for:

> all the words that don't have both substring bba and abb.

and the answer was

```
a*(baa*)*b+b*(a*ab)*a*
```

and I'm like wait a minute is that right ? but that can't make `abb`, which is in the language. So it's gotta wrong.

after getting frustrated tying to  figure out, I came up with my own , would this be all the words that don't have both substring `bba` and `abb` ?

```
(a+ba)*(bb+b+^)
```

edit: after trying more I think this one should work..

```
(b+^)(ab+a)*+b*
```

`^` is an empty string by the way

Comment: Since this looks more like regex theory rather than language implementations of regex, should we assume that `+` means OR (instead of the common implementation meaning of "1 or more")?

Comment: yes + means or , I'm glad you asked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to make an edit so the question doesn't get too long...I'll just do it here

The regex `a*(baa*)*b+b*(a*ab)*a`*` does match abb ? would this work ?

`a*` matches a

`(baa*)*` matches empty string

`b+` matches bb,

`(a*ab)*a*` matches empty string.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679025/how-did-they-get-this-answer-for-the-words-that-dont-have-bba-and-abb